# I got errors when i inset the image in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using IPython  to display Image  in Jupyter notebook. I would like to insert the image but i continuously got the below errors . I am struggling to do this and any advice would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The last line of the error says `No such file or directory: 'Desktop able.jpg.'`
In your filename `Desktop\table.jpg`, `\t` is being interpreted as a tab character. Thats why the "t" in "table" isn't showing up in the error. Try using a double backslash like this: `image("Desktop\\table.jpg")`